# Generated snapshot with jest-styled-components out of order in different environments

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I'm working on a project using styled-components and jest with snapshot testing for initial renders of my React components. I can run these tests locally, which generates snapshots as expected. The test files along with the generated snapshots are all checked in to version control. Later, when running CI steps, tests coming back failing due to out of order class names with identical content.

Snapshot:

```
exports[`TransparentListItem should render 1`] = `
.c0 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #8288A0 !important;
}

.c2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -webkit-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  -moz-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  -ms-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #44485B;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

<div
  className="c0"
>
  <h4
    className="c1 c2"
    size={4}
  />
</div>
`;
```

Test Output:

```
 FAIL  src/components/TransparentListItem/TransparentListItem.test.js (14.986s)
  ● TransparentListItem › should render

    expect(value).toMatchSnapshot()

    Received value does not match stored snapshot 1.

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    @@ -1,5 +1,20 @@
    + .c2 {
    +   font-weight: 600;
    +   font-size: 16px;
    +   line-height: 22px;
    +   -webkit-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    +   -moz-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    +   -ms-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    +   letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    +   font-family: 'Nunito Sans',sans-serif;
    +   font-weight: 500;
    +   color: #44485B;
    +   margin-bottom: 10px;
    +   margin-top: 10px;
    + }
    + 
      .c0 {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    @@ -12,25 +27,10 @@
      .c1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: #8288A0 !important;
      }

    - .c2 {
    -   font-weight: 600;
    -   font-size: 16px;
    -   line-height: 22px;
    -   -webkit-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    -   -moz-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    -   -ms-letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    -   letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    -   font-family: 'Nunito Sans',sans-serif;
    -   font-weight: 500;
    -   color: #44485B;
    -   margin-bottom: 10px;
    -   margin-top: 10px;
    - }
    - 
      <div
        className="c0"
      >
        <h4
          className="c1 c2"

       7 |   it('should render', () => {
       8 |     const tree = renderer.create(<TransparentListItem />).toJSON();
    >  9 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      10 |   });
      11 | });
      12 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/TransparentListItem/TransparentListItem.test.js:9:18)
```

In this case `c2` is saved underneath `c1`, but when the test runs it appears above `c0`.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but for anyone who has looking, I've got the same problem that was solved with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673930/12432424

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the snapshot to match the currently generated class names. Try `jest --u` or `jest --updateSnapshot` it should update the class names.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe the OP wasn't looking for a way to update his snapshots - instead, he was looking for why this ordering got changed.